# How to configure Azure Notification Hub to use APNS token authentication mode?

Tags: azure, authentication, apple-push-notifications, token, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to add APNS connection in Azure Notification Hub with Token as authentication mode.

I have searched around but I am not able to find any guides anywhere to make this work.

Maybe someone has a link to a guide showing how to find the information needed?

I tried to create a "APNs Auth Key" in Apple developer console, but that gives me a .p8 file and the token inside that file does not seem to be accepted, so I guess I need to find the token somewhere else.

I hope someone have a link to a guide for setting this up and find the information needed.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Update (Apr 2018)*: @Krumelur reports in the comments that the blog article is out of date. Check out his suggestion on how to fix it to avoid getting errors.

---

*Update (June 2017)*: There is now an official Microsoft post about [Token-based (HTTP/2) Authentication for APNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-http2-token-authentification).

---

*Original answer (May 2017)*:

[Token Based Authentication and HTTP/2 Example with APNS](http://gobiko.com/blog/token-based-authentication-http2-example-apns/) is a good step by step guide of how to get those values from your Apple Developer Account.

- `Key ID` in Azure Portal is what `APNS_KEY_ID` is in the sample above
- `App Name` in Azure Portal is your app name
- `App ID` in Azure Portal is what `TEAM_ID` is in the sample above
- `Token` in Azure Portal is the contents of the file referred to in `APNS_AUTH_KEY` variable in the sample above

Do not forget to keep track which keys and tokens are sandbox and which are production endpoint ones.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I think it is important to note that `App Name` is not just a name. It is you fully qualified name like "com.company.app"

Comment: is token path to p8 file?

Comment: @sof98789, in this case, it's the contents of the file. Open it in any editor and paste the value into the `Token` box.

Comment: The documentation is no longer correct as the UI in the Azure portal has changed. It's now labeled "Key ID", "Bundle ID", "Team ID" and "Token". When entering the required info, the portal returns with an error about not base-64 formatted content. If you remove the "---BEGIN PRIVATE KEY--" and "---END PRIVATE KEY---" part it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is out of date. It is now looking for

Key ID
Bundle ID
Team ID
Token

Answer (score 0):

Everything is described now in the [documentation here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/////notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-http2-token-authentification)